# Random Forest in R

Tags: r, tree, random-forest

If `x` is a Random Forest in R, for example,

```
x <- cforest (y~ a+b+c, data = football),
```

what does `x[[9]]` mean?

Answer (score 6):

You can't subset this object, so in some sense, `x[[9]]` is nothing, it is not accessible as such.

`x` is an object of S4 class `"RandomForest-class"`. This class is documented on help page `?'RandomForest-class'`. The slots of this object are named and described there. You can also get the slot names via `slotNames()`

```
library("party")
foo <- cforest(ME ~ ., data = mammoexp, control = cforest_unbiased(ntree = 50))

> slotNames(foo)
 [1] "ensemble"            "where"               "weights"            
 [4] "initweights"         "data"                "responses"          
 [7] "cond_distr_response" "predict_response"    "prediction_weights" 
[10] "get_where"           "update"
```

If by `x[[9]]` you meant the 9th slot, then that is `predict_weights` and `?'RandomForest-class'` tells us that this is

```
 ‘prediction_weights’: a function for extracting weights from
      terminal nodes.
```